# Search list that contain object attribute and print/return object Python

Tags: python, search, object, filter, lambda

I've got a object in which I'm searching if the attribute `title` matches with my search

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.title = title

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s is the title " % self.title
```

How can I print the object when it's invoked? Here is how I'm searching for it.

```
search = " ".join(s[1:]).lower()
if any(search in str(a.title).lower() for a in something):
    print filter(lambda x: search in str(x.title),something)
```

---

`If any(...)` will check if any part of the search matches with my object's title and will return true if found anything.

---

`filter(...)` prints the object, **but here is where I'm having issues with** it prints:

---

`[<__main__.Something object at 0x0000000002C93B38>, <__main__.Something object at 0x0000000002D33828>]`

---

I know that this is an object, why is it not printing through the `__str__(self)` method? How can I evoke the print function from my object `Something`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I would create a filter first to get the items which match your criteria.  Then I would iterate over that and do whatever you want with it:

```
generator = (x for x in something if search in str(x.title).lower())
for item in generator:
   print item
```

The advantage here is that you do the filtering ahead of time (without `filter`) and you only do the filtering test once.

Comment: The generator object you have shown me is very useful. Since you enclosed it in `()`, you've made it a non-iterate object. But if I enclosed it in `[]` would that change the the functionality of the generator object? It shows that it works on my side, so are there any differences between `()` and `[]`?

Comment: Can one generator only search one object's attribute? Say I want to also search `Something.anotherAttr` or `AnotherObj.title`, for this I will need to create another generator object correct?

Comment: @czl -- regarding your first question, `(... for ... in ...)` is a generator expression.  `[... for ... in ...]` is a list comprehension.  The first one creates an object which can be iterated over and not much else.  The second one creates a `list`.  The first is memory efficient since it doesn't store the values -- it only calculates them as it needs them.  The second is nice because at the end of the day, you have a list which is easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the string representation of the *list*, and not each item in the list.

You can do:

```
print map(str, filter(lambda x: search in str(x.title),something))
```

Comment: Yes that can do. Is this method I'm using more "Pythonic"?

Comment: @user2836917 I don't see a need for the `any()` here. You could just do `map(filter(lambda x: search in str(x.title), something))` or as a list comprehension (which I would do): `[str(i) for i in something if search in str(x.title)]`